# How does std::future affects the lifetime of an associated std::packaged_task?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, object-lifetime, std-future

I have an `std::packaged_task` containing a lambda that captures a variable by copy. When this `std::packaged_task` is deleted, I would expect the variable living inside the lambda to be destructed, but I noticed that if I get the associated `std::future` for this `std::packaged_task`, the `future` object extends the lifetime of the variable inside the lambda.

For example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <future>

class Dummy
{
public:
    Dummy() {std::cout << this << ": default constructed;" << std::endl;}
    Dummy(const Dummy&) {std::cout << this << ": copy constructed;" << std::endl;}
    Dummy(Dummy&&) {std::cout << this << ": move constructed;" << std::endl;}
    ~Dummy() {std::cout << this << ": destructed;" << std::endl;}
};

int main()
{
    std::packaged_task<void()>* p_task;
    {
        Dummy ScopedDummy;
        p_task = new std::packaged_task<void()>([ScopedDummy](){std::cout << "lambda call with: " << &ScopedDummy << std::endl;});
        std::cout << "p_task completed" << std::endl;
    }
    {
        std::future<void> future_result;
        {
            future_result = p_task->get_future();
            (*p_task)();
            delete p_task;
        }
        std::cout << "after p_task has been deleted, the scope of future_result determines the scope of the dummy inside p_task" << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << "p_task cleans up when future_result dies" << std::endl;
}
```

A possible output is:

```
0x7fff9cf873fe: default constructed;
0x7fff9cf873ff: copy constructed;
0x1904b38: move constructed;
0x7fff9cf873ff: destructed;
0x7fff9cf873fe: destructed;
lambda call with: 0x1904b38
after p_task has been deleted, the scope of future_result determines the scope of the dummy inside p_task
0x1904b38: destructed;
p_task cleans up when future_result dies
```

So the object inside the lambda has its lifetime extended by the scope of `future_result`.

If we comment out the line `future_result = p_task->get_future();`, a possible output is:

```
0x7fff57087896: default constructed;
0x7fff57087897: copy constructed;
0x197cb38: move constructed;
0x7fff57087897: destructed;
0x7fff57087896: destructed;
lambda call with: 0x197cb38
0x197cb38: destructed;
after p_task has been deleted, the scope of future_result determines the scope of the dummy inside p_task
p_task cleans up when future_result dies
```

I have been wondering what mechanism comes into play here, does `std::future` contains some link that keeps associated objects alive?

Comment: what compiler are you using ? clang produces the expected output, that is, the task is destructed when the packaged task is... it looks like your compiler considers the task as part of the shared state, this does not look correct to me ...

Comment: I am using gcc 7.2.0. You are right, clang really does produce the second output. Do you think this would count as a bug?

Comment: ok, [gcc libstdc++ sources](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-7.2.0/libstdc++/api/a00074_source.html#l01476) shows that the task is indeed stored in the shared state. This seems wrong to me, although the standard does not explicitly prohibit storing a copy in the shared state ... dunnow, let's see what others say ...

Comment: rethinking about it, gcc behavior turns out legal (although the standard seems not fully consistent about this ), I'll post an answer later ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

looking at [gcc7.2.0 packaged_task sources](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-7.2.0/libstdc++/api/a00074_source.html#l01476), we read:

```
packaged_task(allocator_arg_t, const _Alloc &__a, _Fn &&__fn)
    : _M_state(__create_task_state<_Res(_ArgTypes...)>(std::forward<_Fn>(__fn), __a)){}

~packaged_task()
{
  if (static_cast<bool>(_M_state) && !_M_state.unique())
    _M_state->_M_break_promise(std::move(_M_state->_M_result));
}
```

where `_M_state` is a shared_ptr to the internal packaged_task shared state. So, it turns out that *gcc* stores the callable as part of the packaged_task *shared state*, hence binding the callable lifetime to whom among packaged_task,future,shared_future dies last.

in comparison, *clang* does not, destroying the callable when the packaged task gets destroyed ( in fact, my copy of clang will store the callable as a proper member ).

Who's right ? the standard is not very clear about the stored task lifetime; from one side, we have

> **[[futures.task]]**
>
> packaged_task defines a type for **wrapping a function or callable object** so that the return value of the function or callable object is stored in a future when it is invoked.
>
> packaged_task(F&& f)[...]Constructs a new packaged_task object with a shared state and initializes the **object’s stored task** with std::forward(f).
>
> packaged_task(packaged_task&& rhs)[...]**Moves the stored task** from rhs to *this.
>
> reset()[...]Effects: As if *this = packaged_task(std::move(f)), where f is the task **stored in *this**.

that suggests the callable is owned by the packaged_task, but we also have

> **[[futures.state]]**
>
> -Many of the classes introduced in this subclause use some state to communicate results. **This shared state consists of some state information and some (possibly not yet evaluated) result**, which can be a (possibly void) value or an exception. [ Note: Futures, promises, and tasks defined in this clause reference such shared state. —endnote]
>
> -[ Note: The result can be any kind of object **including a function to compute that result**, as by async [...]]

and

> **[futures.task.members]**
>
> -packaged_task(F&& f);[...]Invoking a copy of f shall behave the same as invoking f[...]
>   -~packaged_task(); Effects: Abandons any shared state

suggesting that a callable can be stored in the shared state and that one should not rely on any callable per-instance behaviour ( **this may be interpreted to include the callable end of lifetime side-effects**; by the way, this also implies that your callable is not strictly valid, because it behaves differently from its copy ); moreover, nothing is mentioned about the stored task in the dtor.

All in all, I think clang follows the wording more consistently, although nothing seems *explicitly* forbidding gcc behavior. That said, I agree this should be better documented because it may result in surprising bugs otherwise ...

Comment: +1 Prompted by an application bug ticket I received, I have written a small test program that confirms this behavior for `std::async`. It gets even worse when a  `shared_future` is created because then the task will not be destroyed on `get()` but only on the destruction of the last `shared_future` – which is expected from what you have described. (I have now replaced the offending code with uses of a dependency tracking thread pool, written by yours truly, which destroys the task immediately after it has run to completion.)